# Convert from military time to UTC in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a dataset, df1, I would like to convert all the values from the 24 hour clock to UTC.

```
  Date               Name

  1/2/2020 16:46      A
  1/2/2020 16:51      B
```

I Would like

```
  Date                  Name

  1/2/2020 4:46:47 PM      A
  1/2/2020 4:51:44 PM      B
```

I have tried:

```
  df$Date<- format(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

dput:

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1/2/2020 16:46", 
 "1/2/2020 16:51"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert the data to `POSIXct` format and then use `format` to get data in the required format.

```
df$Date <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
                  "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
#Can also use mdy_hm from lubridate
#df$Date <- format(lubridate::mdy_hm(df$Date), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
df

#                    Date Name
#1 01/02/2020 04:46:00 PM    A
#2 01/02/2020 04:51:00 PM    B
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to actually convert a string in one format to a string in another format rather than having it as a (more useful) actual date/time, you can use a little arithmetic and string chopping along with `mapply`:

```r
splits <- strsplit(as.character(df$Date), " |:")
Hours <- as.numeric(sapply(splits, `[`, 2))
AMPM <- c(" AM", " PM")[Hours %/% 12 + 1]
Hours <- Hours %% 13 + Hours %/% 13
df$Date <- mapply(function(x, y, z) paste0(x[1], " ", y, ":", x[3], z), splits, Hours, AMPM)

df
#>               Date Name
#> 1 1/2/2020 4:46 PM    A
#> 2 1/2/2020 4:51 PM    B
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the same assumptions as the previous answer by Allan, here is another way of converting from 24 hour to 12 hour.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
      date = c(ymd_hms("2020/01/02 16:46:00", "2020/01/02 16:51:00", tz = "UTC")),
      name = c("A", "B")
      )

df %>% 
    mutate(date_hour = hour(date),
       am_pm = if_else(date_hour > 12, "PM", "AM"),
       date_hour = if_else(date_hour > 12, date_hour - 12, date_hour - 0),
       newdatetime = paste0(date(date), " ", date_hour , ":", minute(date), " ", am_pm)) %>% 
    select(-c(date_hour, am_pm))

df
 # A tibble: 2 x 3
  date                name  newdatetime       
 <dttm>              <chr> <chr>             
 1 2020-01-02 16:46:00 A     2020-01-02 4:46 PM
 2 2020-01-02 16:51:00 B     2020-01-02 4:51 PM
```

Hope this helps!